# Please explain the usage of context in react.js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am studying the frontend code of the nomadgram app below . . .

https://github.com/nomadcoders/nomadgram.git

The code from `frontend/src/components/footer/index.js` is listed below and it has lines in it such as:

`<li className={styles.listItem}>{context.t("About Us")}</li>`

I do not understand the usage of the `context.t("About Us")` code.  This style usage of context is all over the place on this app and I cannot seem to wrap my head around it.

Some help would be appreciated !!

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import styles from "./styles.scss";

const Footer = (props, context) => (
  <footer className={styles.footer}>
    <div className={styles.column}>
      <nav className={styles.nav}>
        <ul className={styles.list}>
          <li className={styles.listItem}>{context.t("About Us")}</li>
          <li className={styles.listItem}>{context.t("Support")}</li>
          <li className={styles.listItem}>{context.t("Blog")}</li>
          <li className={styles.listItem}>{context.t("Press")}</li>
          <li className={styles.listItem}>{context.t("API")}</li>
          <li className={styles.listItem}>{context.t("Jobs")}</li>
          <li className={styles.listItem}>{context.t("Privacy")}</li>
          <li className={styles.listItem}>{context.t("Terms")}</li>
          <li className={styles.listItem}>{context.t("Directory")}</li>
          <li className={styles.listItem}>{context.t("Language")}</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div className={styles.column}>
      <span className={styles.copyright}>© 2017 Nomadgram</span>
    </div>
  </footer>
);

Footer.contextTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default Footer;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main things that a component is driven by: state, and props. state is internal to the component, and props is passed down by the parent component.

But sometimes it can be combersome to pass props down through a long chain of components, and so there's a third thing that can be used: context. Context allows a component to make some data available to its descendants, without knowing exactly which descendants need it.

So somewhere higher up the component tree, there's a component that looks something like this, and is sharing a function named `t` with any descendant that wants it:

```
class MyProviderComponent extends React.Component {
  getChildContext() {
    return {
      t: function (key) {
        return 'something something';
      }
    }
  }
}

MyProviderComponent.childContextTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

If i had to guess, the real `t` function probably does string translation.

---

Be aware that your code and the code i've added is using the old context api. In React 16 they introduced a new context api. You can read more about the [current context api here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and the [old api here](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html)

Comment: Well this must be a mistake in the code . . . I cannot find the `getChildContext()` function call anywhere . . .

Comment: In frontend/src/index.js they render an I18n component. This component is imported from redux-i18n and is the one that calls getChildContext. https://github.com/APSL/redux-i18n/blob/master/src/component/component.js